# Не могу очистку сделать при нажатии jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Проблема в том, что при открытом поле"текст 1" я нажимаю на "кнопку 2" и этот текст не скрывается (тоесть хочу сделать, после нажатие вылазила то, что принадлежит это кнопке, не понимаю как очистку сделать)

скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.spoiler-body').hide();
  $('.spoiler-title').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

css

```
.spoiler-title { cursor: pointer; }
.spoiler-body { display: none; }
```

html

```
<div class="spoiler-title">Кнопка 1</div>
<div class="spoiler-body">Текст 1</div>
<div class="spoiler-title">Кнопка 2</div>
<div class="spoiler-body">Текст 2</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Текст1" при нажатии на "Кнопку2" не скрывается потому, что вы не скрываете тексты не идущие сразу за кнопкой.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $all_bodys  = $('.spoiler-body')
    $all_bodys.hide();

    $('.spoiler-title').click(function(){
       $next = $( this ).next();
       $all_bodys.not( $next ).hide() //скрыть все кроме следующей
       $next().toggle(); //показать/скрыть следующую за кнопкой.
    }); 
});
```

UPDATE: Поправлено скрытие. Будет скрывать все кроме следующей за кнопкой. В предыдущей версии скрывало все, соответсвенно `toggle` всегда работал только на открывание.